# simple switch for mains power

Tags: switches, mains, speakers

i dont know much about electronics.. ive got a set of active speakers set up, but currently have no way to switch them on/off easily without going around to each one and flicking the switch.. so i want to wire up a nice little box that connects to the mains, and then to each speaker. i've got this switch

[image]

rated at 16a 250v

basically i need to know if this switch is suitable, its not going to do any crazy overload spike that will damage my equipment.. and also, that it will be ok for the earth and cold wires to be connected to the device 24/7 as this will only break the hot wire.. thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Could you include a wiring diagram or schematic of what you propose to do?

Comment: "connecting device to earth only" in neither a particularly fitting nor descriptive title for the question...

Comment: Please correct your title so it match's your question. Proper capitalization, grammar and punctuation would make this much more readable. Do not comment on things your not changing-it just adds clutter. You seem to be interrupting the 'HOT' wire only.

Comment: I would vote for Richard's last sentence below - A simple power-strip with a switch.

Answer (score 1):

Your switch is likely suitable for your project. You provided the specifications for the switch, but you omitted the specifications for your load (your active speakers).

Yes, it is perfectly acceptable to switch only the hot/live side of the power mains and leave the cold/neutral connected.  Of course, you must remember to also include suitable wiring for the green-wire safety ground.

However, you said "i don't know much about electronics.." and this is a project that involves power mains wiring.  It is rather an ambitious project for your level of experience.  It would seem much simpler to use something readily available like a simple power strip.

Comment: thanks a lot, though i'm not sure what you mean about the green wire. When you say suitable wiring do you mean a suitable medium? or just that it is wired up correctly.

Comment: a power strip and a switch would do fine, the main thing is that i can put the switch on my desk so i dont have to grovel around on the floor.

Comment: If you don't understand what the green-wire ground is, PLEASE DO NOT attempt this project. You are not ready for a project involving dangerous mains power.  There are dozens of commercial products off the shelf that provide remote power switching control. Both wired and wireless.